# Compare string with uint32_t by dereference

Tags: c, parsing, input, cross-platform, unsigned-integer

Say for instance I wanted to parse input from the user/stdin, this input was a string (`char*` / `char []`). I know I can typecast a string's memory address pointer to a `uint32_t` pointer and dereference said `uint32_t` pointer to extract a `unsigned int` value which is the same across most architectures (that I've tested). Is this safe? Can it lead to bugs/undefined behavior? i.e. just in general a bad idea?

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void) {
    char data[] = "status";
    printf("%u\n", *(uint32_t*)data);

    return 0;
}
```

Will result in `1952543859` on 64bit and 32bit (windows & linux, not tested on MAC/unix system)

Is it safe to do the below operation?:

```
char str_from_input[] = "status";
if (*(uint32_t*)str_from_input == 1952543859)
   //... execute some code oriented around "status".
```

My obvious aim is to reduce computations by not repeatedly calling string parsing functions like `strcmp` and `strncmp` by a direct `uint32_t` check/if statement.

Comment: `(uint32_t*)data`  is a problem should it not meet alignment requirements of `uint32_t`.  Use `memcpy()`.

Comment: By alignment requirements you mean strict aliasing? Would the code by correct if I memcpy'd the data to  a `unit32_t` memory location, it would be safe

Comment: dkkl_codex, My comment was about alignment, not aliasing.  IAC, you have a good answer below.

Comment: "obvious aim is to reduce computations by ..." --> [Is premature optimization really the root of all evil?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil)

Answer (score 2):

> … typecast a string's memory address pointer to a uint32_t pointer…
> Is this safe?

No. If the string is not properly aligned for a `uint32_t`, the behavior of the cast is not defined, per C 2018 6.3.2.3 7: “… If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined…”

Dereferencing the resulting pointer accesses the string using a type that is inappropriate for it, violating the aliasing rule in 6.5 7, and the behavior is not defined by the C standard.

> Can it lead to bugs/undefined behavior?

Yes.

> i.e. just in general a bad idea?

Yes.

> Is it safe to do the below operation?:

No.

To reinterpret the bytes in a string as a `uint32_t`, use:

```
uint32_t t;
memcpy(&t, string, sizeof t);
printf("%" PRIu32 "\n", t);
```

(`memcpy` is declared in `<string.h>`, and `PRIu32` is declared in `<inttypes.h>`.)

To copy the bytes of a `uint32_t` into a string, use `memcpy(string, &t, sizeof t);`.

A good C compiler is likely to replace the `memcpy` calls with direct data move instructions, if feasible.

> My obvious aim is to reduce computations by not repeatedly calling string parsing functions like `strcmp` and `strncmp` by a direct `uint32_t` check/if statement.

Avoid using kludges. Write clear code and let the compiler optimize.

Comment: So I should just use `strcmp`/`strncmp` in otherwords ? UnlessI used `memcpy`?

Comment: So would the call to `memcpy` + if statement to check the `uint32_t` value, like in my example except without a reinterpret cast be faster than a call to `strcmp` or `strncmp`?

Comment: Stop seeking kludges. Write `strcmp`  or `strncmp` to compare strings or parts of them. Do not worry about their performance until it is actually impairing your application or you have the expertise required to analyze performance in detail.